# hololens 2 tcp client - access permissions

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine, tcp, client, hololens

I develop for hololens 2 in unity and now got a problem with socket communication.
I am trying to get TCP client on hololens 2 and if I want to connect to TCP server I got the following error on my glasses (in unity it works):
*System.Exception: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.*

I already checked the permissions in Player Settings: InternetClient, InternetClientServer, PrivateNetworkClientServer

**Using**:

Unity 2019.4.2f1

Api Compatibility Level .NET 4.x

Scripting Backend: IL2CPP

Target SDK Version: 10.0.18362.0

using: Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket

any suggests?

Comment: It seems likely your app cannot bind to the port, it may be held by other process. Could you try to select another port for listening?
Besides, we always recommend the Unity LTS (Long Term Support) stream as the best version so that we can avoid some known issue, and the current recommendation is to use Unity 2019.4.11f1: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases Therefore, could you upgrade your unity version first and then try this function again?

Comment: I tried to install 2019.4.11f1 Version but without success. I want to connect to local network with port 10004. If I try client connection from other computer it works well. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the connection issue a long time ago while working on Hololens1. I haven't worked on Hololens2 network protocols. But one of the biggest problem I faced was Hololens UWP C# and Unity C# are different from each other and they create a conflict. You may need to specify the directive for the communication. Check out this [link](https://foxypanda.me/tcp-client-in-a-uwp-unity-app-on-hololens/). This guys explained the problem and solution really well.

My suggestion is if you are not sending constant requests and periodically sending the data, try creating a server based application which accepts REST API calls. That will be a much robust solution.

Comment: thanks for your response. I just checked the manifest and there were no capabilities created from unity after build created although in Player setting was it checked and voila the connection works now!

Comment: Could you be more specific about which capability needs to be checked?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Unity 2019.4.13f1 and tcp connection works fine.

Example code:

```
public string ServerIp = "192.168.31.12";
private const int PORT = 9999;
private Socket Client;
public void CreateClient()
{
    Debug.Log("\r\nCreating Client...");

    Thread createClientAndConnect = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIp), PORT);
            Client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Client.Connect(serverEP);

            Thread listenToServer = new Thread(Receive);
            listenToServer.IsBackground = true;
            listenToServer.Start(Client);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error when creating client");
            Debug.LogError(e.Message);
        }
    });
    createClientAndConnect.IsBackground = true;
    createClientAndConnect.Start();

    Debug.Log("Client is created");
}
```